# как сложить два вводимых значения на django rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

## Проблема

Доброго времени суток, я делаю простое финансовое приложение на Django Rest(Для себя). Приложение должно считать затраты за опр.время, и проблема в том что данные вводятся и изменяются на те которые я изменил: например у меня на балансе 1000 руб я перевожу другу 600 руб и на балансе должно остаться 400,но при вводе баланс остаётся таким каким был и ничего не спишется и сумма перевода останется прежней даже если сумма перевода превысит баланс.

#### Так вот

Я попытался написать простую логику из `if` и `else` в сериалайзере, но дошёл только до того,что я принимаю не вводимые данные в эти поля а сами эти поля.`(закоментированный код в serialiser.py)`

#### Пожалуста

Пожалуйста хотябы подскажите где найти документацию где говорится как работать с водимыми данными в Django Rest.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction
import  random
# from django.contrib.auth import  get_user_model
# User = get_user_model()
# Create your models here.


class Wolf(models.Model):
    Trans_TYPE = (
        ('income', 'Income'),
        ('withdrawal of funds', 'Withdrawal of funds')
    )
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='First Name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Second Name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(verbose_name='email', unique=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='balance', default=0, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    transaction = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Transaction', choices=Trans_TYPE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='amount', max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Trans_from = models.CharField(verbose_name='From / To whom', max_length=100, blank=True)
```

## serialisers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Wolf

class WolfListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wolf
        fields = '__all__'



class WolfSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wolf
        fields = '__all__'


class WolfTranSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wolf
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'balance', 'transaction', 'amount']

        # Bal = fields[2]
        # Amon = fields[4]
        # Trns = fields[3]
        #
        # int(Bal)
        # int(Amon)
        #
        # def make_transaction(self, Bal, Amon, Trns):
        #     if Bal < Amon:
        #         raise (ValueError('Not enough money'))
        #     else:
        #         if Trns == 'Withdrawal of funds':
        #             Bal -= Amon
        #         else:
        #             Bal += Amon
        #             Wolf.balance == Bal
        #             Wolf.balance.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

serializer это не то место, где должна быть эта логика.

Роль serializer-а, превратить объекти в форму пригодную для отправки их по сети или хранения в файле. Проверка же, условий допустима ли операция,
это бизнес-логика, или по другому логика предметной области.

В простых случаях ее можно поместить в класс модели:

```
class Wolf(models.Model):

  ...

  def make_transaction(self, value, ... другие параметры):
    # тут логика
    if value > self.balance:
       raise NotEnoughMoney()
    self.balance -= value
```

Роль view будет получить параметры из запроса, прочитать модель, вызвать метод с бизнес логикой и сохранить результат. Вот схематичный код:

```
def perform_transaction(request):
   # сначала нужно получить параметры из запроса
   wolf_id = requst.get('wolf_id')
   amount = request.get('amount')
   wolf = Wolf.objects.get(id=wolf_id)
   try:
      wolf.make_transaction(amount, ...)
      wolf.save()
   except NotEnoughMoney:
      # возвращаем страницу с ошибкой
```